# R loop new quartz window size adjustment

Tags: r, plot

I have this code:

```
par(mfrow = c(3,3))
for (i in 1:55) {
matplot(t(rlkandsig[c(i,55),2:5]), type="l", pch=20, lty=1, xlab="time", 
ylab="ctrl_lsm1_ratio")
points(d2[c(i,55,(i+55),110,(i+110),165,(i+165),220),1], d2[c(i,55,(i+55),110,
(i+110),165,(i+165),220),4], col=ifelse(d2[c(i,55,(i+55),110,(i+110),165,(i+165),220),2]==
"yes",1,2),cex=2.0)
legend("topright",legend=c("yes","no"), col=c(1,2), pch=21)
    if (i>9) {
        quartz()
        par(mfrow = c(3,3))
        }
}
```

I'm trying to print multiple graphs (55) so for easier display I would like a new quartz window to pop up and print the next 9 graphs. However I am getting multiple windows and only 1 graph per quartz window. I know this is a simple fix but I can't figure out how.

Comment: You seem to be opening a new window every time `i>9` (ie, `i=10,11,12,13,14...`), but don't you mean to do this every time `i` is divisible by 9? (ie `i=9,18,27,...`). Try `i%%9==0`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! the corrected code is:

```
par(mfrow = c(3,3))
for (i in 1:55) {
    matplot(t(rlkandsig[c(i,55),2:5]), type="l", pch=20, lty=1, xlab="time", 
    ylab="ctrl_lsm1_ratio")
    points(d2[c(i,55,(i+55),110,(i+110),165,(i+165),220),1], d2[c(i,55,(i+55),110,(i+110),165,(i+165),220),4], col=ifelse(d2[c(i,55,(i+55),110,(i+110),
    165,(i+165),220),2]=="yes",1,2),cex=2.0)
    legend("topright",legend=c("yes","no"), col=c(1,2), pch=21)
        if (i >9 & i%%9==0) {
            quartz()
            par(mfrow = c(3,3))
            }
    }
```